# How to map all http requests of the form /rest/* to @Path resource in RestEasy

Tags: java, rest, wildfly, resteasy

I am new to RestEasy framework and I am looking for a way to match all my http requests of the form /rest/* to my @Path annotated resource class PassThroughController. I could not find similar resources to help me. May be I am not sure of what and how to search for my requirement.

Here is my application class:

```
@ApplicationPath("rest")
public class PassThroughService extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> clazzes = new HashSet();
        clazzes.add(PassThroughController.class);

        return clazzes;
    }
}
```

**PassThroughController.java**

```
@Path("/*")
public class PassThroughController
{

    @GET
    public Response all(@Context SecurityContext ctx) {
        Response resp = Response.
                ok("Welcome! "+ ctx.getUserPrincipal().getName()).
                build();

        return resp;
    }
}
```

When I send a request: `http://localhost:8080/{web-context}/rest/userservice/getuserdetails`
I get 404 error. But, I want that any request of the format /rest/* should be intercepted at my PassThroughController class. Once there, I want HTTPServletRequest object so that I can get pathInfo, headers, parametermap and request parameters and call different services using those details.

So, basically I have two requirements:

1. How to call my method?
2. How to get HTTPServletRequest object once the method is invoked?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a `ContainerRequestFilter`. You can't have an endpoint itself intercept calls. See the [JavaDoc](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/container/containerrequestfilter) for more details.